# How can I encourage 5 year old to kick the ball?

Tags: primary-schooler, sports

A 5/6 year old girl really doesn't like to kick the ball. Throwing is much more prefered.

She would kick if a parent insists on it. But on her own volition she would always throw (so that when she plays with her brother or other kids, she may kick it with him 1 or 2 times and then insist that he keep kicking it to her bit she'll **throw** it back to him.

She claims she has no issues physically (it doesn't hurt to kick - and she likes to kick the air in child Tae-Kwon-Do classes; she isn't afraid to fall); and she CAN kick - though not perfectly. This is pretty much the only physical activity she seems to dislike.

What could be the reason and how can I encourage her to kick the ball?

Comment: does she wear the same clothes when out playing ball with other kids as she does at TKD? If she's in a skirt she may be worried about showing her underwear with a wild kick, compared to being in a gi for TKD.

Comment: @Chrys - Interesting approach! But doesn't fit her case, sadly, she has the same attitude when wearing anything including jeans. And it's the same inside the house.

Comment: Situation can mean a lot.  In Tae Kwon Do, she has a role.  When "kickin'" it with the guys, she has another perceived role.  Answering "How do we view ourselves?" is tough... the answer ought to be independent of who we are around.

Comment: @JeremyMiller - her reluctance is the same no matter if she's with her age peers of either gender, her brother, or either of her parents. (or if you're driving at the "social roles" thing, almost every girl in her class plays soccer).

Comment: If everything is the same in all cirumstances and there is absolutely no variation, then why do others vary?  There is only one reason any of us have every done anything: we wanted to.  What motivates her?  Many of your questions deny every possible situation and rationale in their answers and yet you wonder why you get something different.  If your questions are that the person is 100% like everyone else except in 1 area, then the question is VERY specific and who can help?

Comment: I think this a mountain out of a molehill situation.  Unless there is some reason that she really needs to kick a ball, I'd just let it go.

Comment: Sounds like she should be playing baseball.

Answer (score 2):

She may just be used to doing it. If she learned to throw at an early age she might have been stuck with doing that.

You can't really encourage her, but if you keep forcing her to do it, it may take a while so be patient